# Efficent way to replace underscore with char or string

Tags: java, replace, append, stringbuilder

I have researched this topic for a while, but without much success. I did find the StringBuilder and it works wonders, but that's as far as I got. Here is how I got my hangman program to work like it should:

```
  if(strGuess.equalsIgnoreCase("t")){
        mainword.replace(0,1,"T");
        gletters.append('T');      
    }
        else if(strGuess.equalsIgnoreCase("e")){
        mainword.replace(1,2,"E");
        gletters.append('E');       
    }
        else if(strGuess.equalsIgnoreCase("c")){
        mainword.replace(2,3,"C");
        gletters.append('C');         
    }
        else if(strGuess.equalsIgnoreCase("h")){
        mainword.replace(3,4,"H");
        gletters.append('H');      
    }
        else if(strGuess.equalsIgnoreCase("n")){
        mainword.replace(4,5,"N");
        gletters.append('N');      
    }
        else if(strGuess.equalsIgnoreCase("o")){
        mainword.replace(5,6,"O");
        mainword.replace(7,8,"O");
        gletters.append('O');       
    }
        else if(strGuess.equalsIgnoreCase("l")){
        mainword.replace(6,7,"L");
        gletters.append('L');       
    }
         else if(strGuess.equalsIgnoreCase("g")){
        mainword.replace(8,9,"G");
        gletters.append('G');      
    }
        else if(strGuess.equalsIgnoreCase("y")){
        mainword.replace(9,10,"Y");
        gletters.append('Y'); 
    }
        else{
        JOptionPane.showMessageDialog(null, "Sorry, that wasn't in the word!");
        errors++;
        gletters.append(strGuess.toUpperCase());
    }
        SetMain = mainword.toString();
        GuessedLetters = gletters.toString();
        WordLabel.setText(SetMain);
        GuessedLabel.setText(GuessedLetters);
        GuessText.setText(null);
        GuessText.requestFocusInWindow();
```

However, I can't do this for EVERY letter for EVERY word, so is there a simple and efficient way to do this? What I want is to have a loop of some sort so that I would only have to use it once for whatever word. So the word could be technology (like it is above) or apple or pickles or christmas or hello or whatever.

I have tried using a for loop, and I feel the answer lies in that. And if someone could explain the charAt() method and how/where to use it, that'd be good. The closest I got to being more efficient is:

```
for(i = 0; i < GuessWord.length(); i++) { 
    if (GuessWord.charAt(i) == guess2) { 
        mainword.replace(i,i,strGuess.toUpperCase()); 
    }
```

So if you could use that as a basis and go off of it, like fix it? Or tell me something I haven't thought of.

Comment: What's the matter with your for loop/charAt block of code?

Comment: @ZackMacomber, I'm guessing the if condition is never met, because when the button is clicked nothing happens. What should happen is the letter is replaced if the user correctly guesses it

Answer (score 3, accepted):

It's a good question. There's clearly repeated code, so how do you replace all that with something reusable. Actually, you can dispense with all of your code.

That whole code block can be replaced by just one line (that works for every word)!

```
String word = "TECHNOLOGY"; // This is the word the user must guess
mainword = word.replaceAll("[^" + gletters + "]", "_");
```

This uses [`replaceAll()`](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/6/docs/api/java/lang/String.html#replaceAll%28java.lang.String,%20java.lang.String%29) with a regex that means "any letter not already guessed" and replaces it with a underscore character `"_"`. Note that Strings are immutable, and the `replaceAll()` method *returns* the modified String - it doesn't modify the String called on.

Here's some test code to show it in action:

```
public static void main(String[] args) {
    String word = "TECHNOLOGY"; // what the user must guess
    StringBuilder gletters = new StringBuilder("GOTCHA"); // letters guessed
    String mainword = word.replaceAll("[^" + gletters + "]", "_");
    System.out.println(mainword);
}
```

Output:

```
T_CH_O_OG_
```

Comment: by word.replaceAll , what does variable "word" stand for?

Comment: You don't need to store the word as "code" as you are doing; just create a String variable called "word" to hold the value that the user must guess.

Comment: i feel like your answer is the most helpful, and you're on to something. Okay, so say instead of System.out.print I want to use JLabel.setText(mainword). Woul that work? And I have the gletters StringBuilder set to the user's guess, not certain characters

Comment: Of course - I just used that to display it simply. Use your `mainword` and gletter  variables as you do now. It will work. The rest of your code can be further simplified, but I'll leave that to you :)

Comment: okay and last question, how would I use an array of words (the words im using for this hangman game) to replace it? In other words, since String word = "TECHNOLOGY", would String word2 have to be made?

Comment: In that case, use `String[] words; int wordIndex = 5; mainword = words[wordIndex].replaceAll...`

Comment: @user1803676 yes, wordIndex is the index of the word currently being played. eg `wordIndex = (int)(Math.random() * words.length);`

Comment: Good news! It worked, but only does one letter at a time. so for the word apple:
guess a and value is: a _ _ _ _
guess p and value is: _ p p _ _
i want it to be cumalitive. Help?

Comment: @user1803676 you must be clearing the guesses or creating a new object every loop. i guarantee it works - try hard coding  `"apple".replaceAll("[^ap]", "_");` and you'll see the output is `app__`

Comment: `foundword = words[randvalue].replaceAll("[^" + xletters + "]", "_ ");` is what i have in the for loop, where foundword is a string, words[randvalue] is a random word from my string array, and xletters is the letter the user guesses. And it only works for one letter one at a time. I can't get it to be cumulative

Comment: @JavaProdigy `xletters` needs to be **ALL** the letters guessed so far. You need to *add* the guessed letter to it, so *replace* it. `xletters` should be defined *outside* the loop.

Comment: xletters is defined as `StringBuilder xletters = new StringBuilder(strGuess);` above the for loop. Would i use the append() method for this then?